# Grabbing Image with WebRequest causes UI to freeze

Tags: wpf, image, user-interface, httpwebrequest, freeze

I want to grab an image every 3 seconds from an ip camera and put it in a Image control (WPF application).

I'm using this code:

DispatcherTimer definition

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), DispatcherPriority.Background, DispatcherTimer_Tick, Application.Current.Dispatcher);
```

Image grabbing code

```
private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs evA)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
         new Action(() =>
         {
             try
             {
                 BitmapFrame src;
                 var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://camera_ip/cgi-bin/video.cgi?msubmenu=jpg");
                 webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
                 webRequest.Proxy = null;

                 var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
                 var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                 var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
                 src = BitmapFrame.Create(streamReader.BaseStream);

                 imageTelecamera.BeginInit();
                 imageTelecamera.Source = src;
                 imageTelecamera.EndInit();

              }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 DoLogD($"Error: {ex.Message}");
             }
         }
        ));
    }
```

It works fine but when i grab the image the UI freezes for some milliseconds.

Why the dispatcher is not working on the background without affecting the UI?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call `Dispatcher.Invoke` in the Tick handler of a DispatcherTimer, because the handler method is already called in the UI thread. Besides that, Invoke does not call anything in a background thread. It does the opposite: if you call it from a background thread, it invokes an Action in the UI thread.

Comment: You probably want to call your grabbing code in a background thread (e.g. by a `System.Threading.Timer`), and call `imageTelecamera.Source = src;
` in a Dispatcher Action. It's also unclear what `BeginInit` and `EndInit` are supposed to do here, as you seem to be calling them on the Image control, which isn't necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your misunderstanding what the dispatcher is

the dispatcher allows you to send commands to the GUI thread, this means that while your command is executing the GUI thread is paused waiting for it to complete.

the proper use of Dispatcher is to send thread specific tasks to the correct thread to execute them, ie your control has an list of children, the list can only be edited safely from the control so if you need to add or remove a child you use the controls Dispatcher to get the control to execute an add new Item command

here is a complete example

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <DockPanel>
        <Button x:Name="butStart" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="Button_Click">start</Button>
        <TextBlock x:Name="output"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //start taking photo
        Task.Run(()=> TakePhoto() );
    }

    public DispatcherTimer timer { get; } = new DispatcherTimer();

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(timer.IsEnabled)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            butStart.Content = "Start";

            //this works as you are in the main thread
            output.Text += "Time Stopped" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Start();
            butStart.Content = "Stop";
            output.Text += "Time Started" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
    public async void TakePhoto()
    {
        //with out the dispatcher this would error as you are not in the Gui thread so have no access to the Text property
        output.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>output.Text += "Take Photo" + Environment.NewLine);
        //Simulate a long running task
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        output.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>output.Text += "Take Photo - Complete" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

now applied to your code

```
private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs evA)
{
    Task.Run() =>
     {
         try
         {
             BitmapFrame src;
             var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://camera_ip/cgi-bin/video.cgi?msubmenu=jpg");
             webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
             webRequest.Proxy = null;

             var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
             var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
             var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
             src = BitmapFrame.Create(streamReader.BaseStream);

             imageTelecamera.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>
             {
                 imageTelecamera.BeginInit();//not actually required
                 imageTelecamera.Source = src;
                 imageTelecamera.EndInit();//not actually required
             });
          }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             DoLogD($"Error: {ex.Message}");
         }
     }
    ));
}
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but still getting those milliseconds of UI freezes.
I start thinking the problem could be resources allocations (WebRequest, Stream, StreamReader).

Comment: if your system is struggling for resources there iisn't much you can do, thought you could try running the code outside of visual studio as VS is quite a hog, if you are loading High res images into image source then that may be causing the issue as it has to process and display the image instantly, you might get better performance from a `BitmapImage` rather than a `BitmapFrame` as the image is optimised for background loading